# My custom macro works on my pc but crashes on target computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, macros, pyinstaller

I made macro which include tesseract(for image ocr), pyautogui(for keyboard mouse controll), openpyxl(for excell file read and write),PIL(for image capture) and I made that code to .exe file with pyinstaller.

It works perfect on my laptop (windows10 64bit device, I coded it on this laptop) but app crashes occurs on target device(windows7 32bit device).

stragely, the code works well on 10~12(random) macro loops.But after that, It always crash.

At first, it was c_type crash, so I fix my code not to use any c_type things, but it crashes after same 10~12 loops with another python37.dll crash.

I'm sure that python and every python libraries are 32bit.

I can't install any new program such as pycharm or python at all to target computer because of security reason.

Is there any way to figure out what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you some tips to create your app with Pyinstaller that works for most of OS and handle missing dependencies:

1. Use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to build your app. It will give you better results and avoid any conflict with the current python build environment. And always try to install the latest version of Pyinstaller inside your env.
2. Find all of your app dependencies and bundle as many as you can to your final executable as DATA files. Sometimes Pyinstaller can't bundle some modules so you need to check its depends and add them manually to your output executable. You can find more info [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#adding-data-files).
3. If you want your app to run on Older OS like Win7, try to build your app in a Win7 machine. That is because there are some dependencies that come with a new OS like Win10 but they do not exist in Win7 by default.
4. Use debug options with Pyinstaller and your code for better understanding your problem. For example, using `--debug=all` in build time would give you much more info about errors. You can find more info in [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/when-things-go-wrong.html).